# Height changing with ::after and relative positionning

Tags: html, css

I am facing a behavior of my div I cannot fix maybe you know a trick for it. I am trying to do a little horizontal list that changes background when you hover one and displays a little arrow towards the downside. I decided to use the pseudo-class ::after to display the arrow, to display it as a block to put it under the word and have a relative position so it can easily be automatically centered. The problem is when I do so, the height of the list div changes which is quite ugly. I tried the absolute position but it is very repetitive and quite inefficient, is there a trick to remove this behavior?

```css
.liste--horizontal
{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    color: black;
}

.portfolio_selection
{
    background-color: rgb(223, 222, 222);
    padding: 0%;
    margin-top: 4%;
} 

.portfolio_selection_critere
{
    padding: 10px;
}

.portfolio_selection_critere:hover
{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: #3491b2;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #277088;

}

.portfolio_selection_critere:hover::after
{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0em;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;    
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #277088;
    position: relative;
    top: 80%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="portfolio_selection liste--horizontal">
            <li class="portfolio_selection_critere">All works</li>
            <li class="portfolio_selection_critere">Creative</li>
            <li class="portfolio_selection_critere">Corporate</li>
            <li class="portfolio_selection_critere">Portfolio</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution is to make the arrow present on the non hover state and you simply adjust its color and/or opacity on hover:

```css
.liste--horizontal {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: black;
}

.portfolio_selection {
  background-color: rgb(223, 222, 222);
  padding: 0%;
  margin-top: 4%;
}

.portfolio_selection_critere {
  padding: 10px;
}

.portfolio_selection_critere:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: #3491b2;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #277088;
}

.portfolio_selection_critere:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0em;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #277088;
  position: relative;
  top: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}

.portfolio_selection_critere:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="portfolio_selection liste--horizontal">
  <li class="portfolio_selection_critere">All works</li>
  <li class="portfolio_selection_critere">Creative</li>
  <li class="portfolio_selection_critere">Corporate</li>
  <li class="portfolio_selection_critere">Portfolio</li>
</ul>
```

And if you don't want the height to grow make it absolute position and adjust the values of top/left:

```css
.liste--horizontal {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: black;
}

.portfolio_selection {
  background-color: rgb(223, 222, 222);
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 4%;
}

.portfolio_selection_critere {
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative;
}

.portfolio_selection_critere:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: #3491b2;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #277088;
}

.portfolio_selection_critere:after {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #277088;
  top:100%;
  left:calc(50% - 10px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.portfolio_selection_critere:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="portfolio_selection liste--horizontal">
  <li class="portfolio_selection_critere">All works</li>
  <li class="portfolio_selection_critere">Creative</li>
  <li class="portfolio_selection_critere">Corporate</li>
  <li class="portfolio_selection_critere">Portfolio</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't like the absolute positioning in the first place since I forgot to put the parent as relative and I didn't know the "calc" function. With those two things I understand better why everyone advice it. Thank you.